# Count NULL in one column as a wildcard for a GROUP BY Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to do a `GROUP BY` in Microsoft SQL Server, and I want to include NULL's as a "wildcard"

```
SELECT DNS, TYPE, PORT 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY DNS, TYPE, PORT
```

But, I need the ones in red (see image below) to count as a match with each other, as well as any with actual matching numbers - because NULL matches with all of them.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks!

[image: UPDATED]

Comment: Please include the expected result.

Comment: server1 38169 2 , server 2 90195 2, server 3 376866 2  OR just a list of rows that have matches. So NULL or a matching number would count as a match. If there are two different port# PLUS a NULL, i'd like to count those as 3, not NULL Matching both individually.

Comment: Why are you associating NULL with `49698` and not with `3661`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that should count as 3 and be highlighted in red

Comment: updated pic - if just the red rows could be returned, that would probably be a better result than just a count

Comment: What would really help here is consumable sample data and desired output. As posted this just doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you are trying to do is find all the records where there is more than 1 record when grouped by DNS and Type. Grouping by port will not work as that grouping will, based on your sample data, always return 1.

This simple query should do it.. I've included replicating your sample data here too.

*If you post questions in the future, please provide sample data like this, NOT in images*

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (DNS varchar(10), [Type] INT, Port INT)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('server1', 38169, 3661),
('server1', 38169, 49698),
('server1', 38169, NULL),
('server1', 45039, NULL),
('server1', 105297, NULL),
('server1', 378359, NULL),
('server1', 378360, NULL),
('server2', 38169, 3661),
('server2', 38169, 49708),
('server2', 38169, 49710),
('server2', 45039, NULL),
('server2', 90195, 23),
('server2', 90195, NULL),
('server2', 378360, NULL),
('server3', 45039, NULL),
('server3', 90044, NULL),
('server3', 376866, 443),
('server3', 376866, 80),
('server3', 376866, NULL),
('server3', 377913, NULL),
('server3', 377914, NULL),
('server4', 38739, 22),
('server4', 38739, 22)

SELECT DNS, [Type], Port 
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT * 
            , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY DNS, [Type]) as rcount
            FROM @t 
        ) a 
    WHERE a.rcount >1
```

This returns the following results

[image]

This does not match your red rows (server 2 38169 is not highlighted but appears to match you criteria?)

If this doesn't help, then post some sample data we can work with and the expected results.